# How to use multiple stored procedures with join tables in one view/controller?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, stored-procedures

I have created multiple stored procedures with join operations in it. I am trying to use these stored procedures in my ASP.NET MVC application but it's not working. I am calling these stored procedures on single view. I am using Entity Framework for comm. to database.

Basically, I have to call these stored procedures bases on particular condition that means have to switch between stored procedures on single view.

Does anyone have idea to call such stored procedure in a single view?

Here are my two stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetTotalRecordsByAccountNumber
    @branch varchar(4),
    @basic varchar(6),
    @suffix varchar(3)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        Date AS 'Date',
        desc1 + RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(desc2, ''))) + '' +
                RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(desc2, ''))) AS 'Description',
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN (Transactionamt / Currency) END, 0) AS Debit,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN Amount > 0 THEN (Transactionamt / Currency) END, 0) AS Credit,
        (TotalAmount / currency) AS Balance
    FROM
        tbl1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tbl2 ON tbl1.accountnumber = tbl2.accountnumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tbl3 ON tbl1.currency = tbl3.currency
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tbl4 ON tbl1.accountName = tbl4.accountName
    WHERE
        branch = @branch 
        AND basic = @basic 
        AND suffix = @suffix
    ORDER BY 
        date 
END

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetTotalRecordsByDates
    @branch varchar(4),
    @basic varchar(6),
    @suffix varchar(3),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Date AS 'Date',
        desc1 + RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(desc2, ''))) + '' +
                RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(desc2, ''))) AS 'Description',
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN (Transactionamt/Currency) END, 0) AS Debit,
        ISNULL(CASE WHEN Amount > 0 THEN (Transactionamt/Currency) END, 0) AS Credit,
        (TotalAmount/currency) AS Balance
    FROM
        tbl1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tbl2 ON tbl1.accountnumber = tbl2.accountnumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tbl3 ON tbl1.currency = tbl3.currency
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        tbl4 ON tbl1.accountName = tbl4.accountName
    WHERE 
        branch = @branch 
        AND basic = @basic 
        AND suffix = @suffix
        AND date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    ORDER BY 
        date date
END
```

My controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, string accountNo,string date,bool allcheckbox) 
{  
    if(allcheckbox == true) 
    {
       var dc = db.sp_GetTotalRecordsByAccountNumber(accountNo).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
       var dc = db.sp_GetTotalRecordsByDates(accountNo).ToList();
    }

    return view("Index",dc);
}
```

And my view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<ComplexStoredProceduremvc.Models.sp_GetTotalRecordsByAccountNumber_Result>
```

Here, it only gives data by account number if I want to get data by date then I have to change the stored procedure name which is not the correct option.

I hope you will get the problem....waiting for some solutions...Help!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I do not see any reasons why these stored procedures exists. You can create IQuerybale equivalents via LINQ and reuse them in code.

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what result do you have and what result do you want?

Comment: What the stored procedures have to do with your problem? Doesn't matter what do you use , in any case you have to get data from the server  or get 2 sets  of data and use javascript.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have created Stored procedures to fetch data on the basis of account number and by date. And in my controller I have to put a condition checking if a user want data by account number or by date. On this basis we get the result on view. But problem is I can't call 2 Stored procedures on single view so that it can switch accordingly.

Comment: @Sergey check the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can handle both situation with one `SP` like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetTotalRecordsByDates
@branch varchar(4)='0',
@basic varchar(6)='0',
@suffix varchar(3)='0',
@startdate datetime=null,
@enddate datetime=null
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    Date AS 'Date',
    desc1 + RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(desc2, ''))) + '' +
            RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(desc2, ''))) AS 'Description',
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN (Transactionamt/Currency) END, 0) AS Debit,
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN Amount > 0 THEN (Transactionamt/Currency) END, 0) AS Credit,
    (TotalAmount/currency) AS Balance
FROM
    tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbl2 ON tbl1.accountnumber = tbl2.accountnumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbl3 ON tbl1.currency = tbl3.currency
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tbl4 ON tbl1.accountName = tbl4.accountName
WHERE 
    (branch = @branch or @branch='0')
    AND (basic = @basic or @basic='0')
    AND (suffix = @suffix or @suffix ='0')
    AND (date >= @startdate or @startdate is null)
    AND (date <= @enddate or @enddate is null)
ORDER BY 
    date
END
```

Just make sure if you do not want to filter with some `parameter` pass it as `0 or null`. In this case I used `0` for varchar and `null` for date.